# EEGLAB Ways to 60Hz Remove Line Noise and Harmonics

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, noise, eeglab

I am attempting to remove line noise and its harmonics from many EEG datasets in EEGLAB. I have been using the CleanLine plugin to do this. However, it does not work well sometimes for some datasets. For example, here are the log power spectral density plots before and after cleanline.

Before cleanline:
[image].
After cleanline:
[image]

The code that I used is:

```
EEG = pop_cleanline(EEG, 'bandwidth',2,'chanlist',[1:68] ,'computepower',1,'linefreqs',[60:60:420] ,'newversion',0,'normSpectrum',0,'p',0.01,'pad',2,'plotfigures',0,'scanforlines',0,'sigtype','Channels','taperbandwidth',2,'tau',100,'verb',1,'winsize',4,'winstep',1);
```

I have also tried to use a notch filter with a lower edge of 55 and an upper edge of 65, but that does not work well.

Are there any suggestions on what other method of removing line noise and harmonics that I could try? Or is CleanLine the best method? Are there ways we can adjust the parameters of cleanline to allow it to work better?

Comment: About whether the parameters can be adjusted, did you read the [theory](https://github.com/sccn/cleanline/blob/master/Readme.txt#L42) and [tips](https://github.com/sccn/cleanline/blob/master/Readme.txt#L128) sections of the readme.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ica function followed by IClable and delete all the line noise components. If you would go that way, it might be better not leave the clean_line function. I believe that ICA is more likely to create pure line noise components like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied high pass filter of 0.5 Hz already? Consider doing that first, then try cleanline with tweaked parameters (the ones that give the best outcome) followed by ICA.